# Correct use of the word Bitcoin

Tags: protocol, currencies, legal

I'm still unsure when to use `Bitcoin` and when `bitcoin` is more appropriate. Did anyone define when to use the word Bitcoin with a capital `B`? Is one used to talk about the currency as in "3 Bitcoin" and the other for the "bitcoin protocol"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Introduction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Introduction) on the Bitcoin wiki:

> ## Capitalization / Nomenclature
>
> Since Bitcoin is both a currency and a protocol, capitalization can be confusing. Accepted practice is to use Bitcoin (singular with an upper case letter B) to label the protocol, software, and community, and bitcoins (with a lower case b) to label units of the currency.

So, the accepted usage in your example would be "3 bitcoin" and the "Bitcoin protocol".

Comment: So "add the bitcoin amount" with small b is correct as we talk about the units of the currency? Thanks.

Comment: @Greg, So would we say "I have a bitcoin address" or "I have a Bitcoin address"?

Comment: @Pacerier: According to the above, that would be "Bitcoin address".

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin (capital B) is the name of a currency, a technology, and a movement. A bitcoin (small b) is a unit of this currency.

Example: "After hearing about Bitcoin, I've installed a Bitcoin client and bought 3 bitcoins."